# Error: Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT) when using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

**[Problem Statement:](https://www.techiedelight.com/construct-binary-tree-from-inorder-preorder-traversal/)**
To construct a binary tree from a given **inorder** and **preorder** list.

I was able to write the logic but I get the **error** `Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)` and I ain't able to find what's causing this error.

**[Code:](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/p5nYonZCVK)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int key;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(int key){
    {
        this->key=key;
        this->left=this->right=nullptr;
    }
    }
};


class Solution {
public:

Node *construct_bin(int pidx, int s, int e, map<int, int>  m, vector<int> pre){

    if (s>e){
        return nullptr;
    }
    Node * root = new Node(pre[pidx++]);

    int i = m[root->key];
    root->left = construct_bin(pidx, s, i-1, m, pre);
    root->right = construct_bin(pidx, i+1, e, m, pre);

    return root;

}
};



int main()
{
    Solution sol;
    /* Construct the following tree
               1
             /   \
            /     \
           2       3
          /       / \
         /       /   \
        4       5     6
               / \
              /   \
             7     8
    */

    vector<int> inorder = { 4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6 };
    vector<int> preorder = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6 };
    map<int, int> m;
    int co=0;
    for (auto it: inorder){
        m[it] = co++;
    }
    int n = preorder.size();
    Node* x = sol.construct_bin(0,0,n-1,m, preorder);
}
```

**Logic:**

**[image: Logic:]**

Comment: so when you ran your debugger, on what line did it 'abort'?

Comment: @2785528:  the recursion was going for infinite times.

Comment: Imagine you put  break point on the line where you increment pidx.  Do you think you would notice it was not incrementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment `pidx` in `construct_bin`, but you don't do anything with that incremented value. As a result, you call `construct_bin` an infinite number of times and your code eventually runs out of memory or overflows the stack.

Comment: I used that pidx to get the current node and have set the base condition (s>e).

Comment: Then how that problem statement link 's solution is working. Same thing is done there. But it's working there.

Comment: @Pygirl You are certainly running off the end of `pre`. Perhaps `if (s > e)` is intended to prevent this, but it's not working. Take step thorough the function with a debugger and watch what happens. Make sure what happens matches your expectations.

Comment: @Pygirl That code preserves the increment, you throw it away.